# How to compute this type of limit?1

Tags: limits

I am working on a limit problem and I want to know how to compute this type of limits?

$$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac {\sin\left ( \sin a \theta \right ) }{\theta} $$

Can we say that $$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac {\sin\left ( \sin \left ( \sin \left ( \sin \cdots a \theta \right ) \right )\cdots \right ) }{\theta} =a?$$

Comment: Lol; can I know why down vote or I don't have privilege? ?

Comment: I am not one of the down voters, but I suspect the reason for the down votes is that you have not shared any of your own thoughts or shown any work you have done to evaluate the limit.  Sometimes, this is enough to prompt a down vote.  Other times, posted questions without work are not down voted.  So, this system is arbitrary somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \dfrac {\sin\left ( \sin a \theta \right ) }{\theta}=\left[\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin a\theta)}{\sin a\theta}\right]\left(\lim_{\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin a\theta}{\theta}\right)$$

For your second question, notice that the limit you are looking for is the derivative of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(\theta)=\underbrace{\sin\circ\sin\circ\ldots\circ\sin}_{n\text{ times}}(a\theta)$ at $\theta=0$. From Chain Rule you get
\begin{align*}
f'(0)&=\left.\cos\left(\underbrace{\sin\circ\sin\circ\ldots\circ\sin}_{n-1\text{ times}}(a\theta)\right)\times \cos\left(\underbrace{\sin\circ\sin\circ\ldots\circ\sin}_{n-2\text{ times}}(a\theta)\right)\times\ldots\times\cos(a\theta)a\right|_{\;\theta =0}\\
&=\underbrace{\cos(0)\times \cos(0)\times\ldots\ldots\cos(0)}_{n\text{ times}}\times a\\
&=a
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(a\theta))}{\theta}$$=$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\sin(a\theta))}{\sin(a\theta)}\times \frac{\sin(a\theta)}{a\theta}\times a$$=a