# Limit of sin(sin(sin(x)))

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I had an exam with the exercise
$$
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))}{x}\right)
$$

but I needed to solve it without using L'hopital rule but I was not sure how to solve it, do you know how to clear that out?

I understand that
$$
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=1
$$

but I don't get how to clear the inner sinnus.

Comment: Try to see the derivative of the triple sine at zero.

Comment: Cleverer : write $$ \frac{\sin(\sin(\sin x))}{x} = \frac{\sin(\sin(\sin x))}{\sin(\sin x)} \frac{\sin(\sin x)}{\sin x} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$ and think about the three fractions. Pretty sure that this is a duplicate, will try to look for one.

Comment: Maybe not. A couple of posts come close, see e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193778/how-to-compute-this-type-of-limit1?noredirect=1). It also suggests that the limit to be computed is just the derivative of $\sin(\sin(\sin x))$ at $x=0$, so you could use the chain rule as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))}{x} = \frac{\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))}{\sin(\sin(x))} \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{\sin(x)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}
$$

Each of the multiplicands converges to $1$. Hence, so is their product.

Comment: MathJax tip: Write `\sin` instead of `sin`. It's the difference between $\sin$ and $sin$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I copied the formula from the original post.

Comment: Ah, so you did. I just don't expect to see $sin$ in answers. I've now edited the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit I've reformatted my answer accordingly.